# Scroll Area - set widget / layout?

Tags: python, maya, pyside2, qscrollarea

I have a class definition that uses a QVBoxLayout ( main_layout) where I have a few buttons.

Beneath that I currently have a ton of group boxes

I’d like to put those items (after the buttons) , inside a QScrollArea, so the buttons stay ‘locked ‘ at the of my UI and the other widgets can be scrolled through

The problem I have is that the QScrollArea only has a ‘setWidget’ function - how do I pass it the entirety of those other widgets ? I don’t want to have to put them in a different class altogether

Eg QScrollArea.setLayout() would be useful here !

I’ve tried putting all those widgets under a new sub_layout QVBoxLayout , I just now need a scroll widget controlling it

Any thoughts ?

## main v layoyut

```
main_layout  = qw.QVBoxLayout()
self.layout().addLayout(main_layout)

#do it button added to main layout not scroll area

self.run_button = customButton("place between components",parent=self)
self.run_button.setFixedWidth(315)
self.run_button.setFixedHeight(30)
main_layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

#make the scroll area
scrollArea = qw.QScrollArea()
subWidget = qw.QWidget()
subWidget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
sub_layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
subWidget.setLayout(sub_layout)
scrollArea.setWidget(subWidget)

#add it to the main layout
main_layout.addWidget(scrollArea)




#all my extra layouts and widgets for options are declared

#pins v layout
pins_main_v_layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
pins_main_v_layout.setSpacing(4)
pins_main_v_layout.setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2)

#stitching v layout
stitching_main_v_layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
stitching_main_v_layout.setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2)

#cable v layout
cable_main_v_layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
cable_main_v_layout.setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2)


#add the options layouts to the scroll area sub widget


sub_layout.addLayout(pins_main_v_layout)
sub_layout.addLayout(stitching_main_v_layout)
sub_layout.addLayout(cable_main_v_layout)


# all the options and further layouts, widgets declared from here 
# i include one example below

#PINS
#define the contents pins layout

#main pins box
pins_vbox_group_layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
pins_vbox_group_layout.setSpacing(4)
self.pins_group_box = qw.QGroupBox('pins')
self.pins_group_box.setAlignment(qc.Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.pins_group_box.setCheckable(True)
pins_main_v_layout.addWidget(self.pins_group_box)
self.pins_group_box.setLayout(pins_vbox_group_layout)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an intermediate widget where you set the layout and it can be placed in the QScrollArea:

```py
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
widget.setLayout(sub_layout)
scrollarea.setWidget(widget)
```

Comment: Thanks - would all my subsequent widgets and layouts be added to that new ‘sub_layout’ instead then ?

Comment: @blam I modified the code to use the name of your variable

Comment: Thanks - that helped . I am still having problems adding my widgets and layouts to the sub_layout and getting them to display - no errors reported in maya  . I’m using sub_layout.addLayout(myOptionsLayoutA) but it’s not showing up inside the scroll layout. Before it was main_layout.addLayout(myOptionsLayoutA). I’ve ensured the scrollarea is added to the main_layout as well . Eg current stack is main_layout>scrollarea(which has ‘widget’) >>widget (has layout sub_layout) >> sub_layout has my controls, widgets and layouts added there

Comment: I realise my psuedo code typing isn’t helpful, was just illustrating that I’ve added the scroll widget accordingly back to the main layout .

Comment: @blam Without an [MCVE] I can not help you

Comment: No worries , I’ll copy paste from my machine in a second rather than on mobile !

Comment: I pasted the current code snippet as an 'answer' as I couldn't work out how to include a code snippet in a comment - is that OK ?

Comment: @blam No, that section is for answer, the code must be placed as an edition to your question.

Comment: thanks - have removed my answer and added it to original question as an edit

Comment: @blam only change `scrollArea = qw.QScrollArea()` to `scrollArea = qw.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)`

Comment: amazing - thats great now. Thank you ! I could used setFixedWidthHeight on the widget / sub layout too right ?

Comment: @blam I suppose yes, try if it works, that's the best way to know if something works. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct :-)